# Sort the matrix row-wise and column-wise

Tags: algorithm

The solution is available on Geeksforgeeks but the concept is not clear.
If I sort all the rows first and then sort the columns or vice-a-versa. the approach seems to work on some test cases. I would like to know if anyone can come up with a test case where this would fail.

Given a matrix, the goal is to sort the matrix row-wise and column-wise such that the increasing order is maintained in both directions.

For example:

```
enter code here
Input : mat[][] ={4, 1, 3}
                {9, 6, 8}
                {5, 2, 7}
Output : 1 3 4
         2 5 7
         6 8 9
```

for further reference, refer this link
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sort-matrix-row-wise-column-wise/

Comment: What do you mean by "is it going to work"? It is not clear what you are trying to accomplish. Can you provide more details or possibly some example inputs and expected output?

Comment: You should provide the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) standard. It helps us to help you.

Comment: It sounds like you are sorting the rows and columns separate. You need to sort them at the same time, using nested `for` loops. As you mentioned, the [GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sort-matrix-row-wise-column-wise/) example is what you want to aim for.

Answer (score 2):

You are right on this, the problem is ill-defined. The solution is not unique, and sorting on rows first and columns second does not give the same result as sorting on columns first and rows second.

```
Columns, Rows
4 8 2      3 1 2      1 2 3
7 6 9  ->  4 6 5  ->  4 5 6
3 1 5      7 8 9      7 8 9

Rows, Columns
4 8 2      2 4 8      1 3 5
7 6 9  ->  6 7 9  ->  2 4 8
3 1 5      1 3 5      6 7 9
```

Note how both results are "sorted on rows and columns", i.e. all items on the same row are sorted, and all items on the same column are sorted.

It is also worth noting that not all solutions are found by sorting in these ways, for instance:

```
1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the last example. As far as I understand it, the approach works fine on this example in having a matrix where the elements are sorted by rows as well as columns. Thanks

Comment: The last example is another possible result (for the same input matrix as the previous two examples) that is sorted on rows and columns, but cannot be obtained by sorting on rows then columns nor columns then rows. It is still an acceptable answer though, meaning all possible solutions to this problem are not found by the algorithm proposed on the website. So either the problem is not properly defined, or the algorithm is incorrect